# Create Client classes with wsgen

Tags: wsdl, wsgen

I have a wsdl reachable through an url. I'd like to generate client classes for using this web service using wsgen. How I can do it using as a parameter the wsdl url only? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are after is wsimport, not wsgen:

```
wsimport -Xnocompile -keep -d <directory where you want your client class>  <path to the wsdl>
```

-Xnocompile allows you to keep the source